# ¿Preferencia de uso de "capar" o "castrar" según la zona?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

Ayer un compañero se quejaba de que su gato maullaba mucho por la noche. Lo cual llevó al siguiente diálogo:

> — ¿Lo tienes **capado**?
>   — Sí, pero es que uno de mis vecinos tiene una gata.
>   — Eso da igual, si está **capado** no debe afectarle la gata.
>   — Sí le afecta, porque lo tengo sin **castrar**.
>   — ¿Pero no me acabas de decir que sí que lo habías **capado**?
>   — ¿Eh? ¡Ah, que **capado** quiere decir **castrado**! *No lo sabía*.

Debo decir que la última frase me sorprendió bastante (a mí y a varios que estaban escuchando): yo pensaba que "capar" era, por así decirlo, el verbo estándar para referirse a esterilizar un animal.
Incluso el DLE te redirige a "capar" cuando buscas "castrar":

> [**castrar**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=castrar).
>
> 1. tr. [**capar**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=capar) (‖ extirpar los órganos genitales).
>
>    > De *capón*<sup>1</sup>.
>    >
>    > 1. tr. Extirpar o inutilizar los órganos genitales a una persona o a un animal.

Lo más curioso de todo es que tanto él como yo *somos de la misma ciudad*. Me habría esperado esta confusión hablando con alguien de otra región o país, pero no con un paisano...

En cualquier caso, esto me hace plantearme la pregunta:
**¿En qué países o zonas de habla hispana se utiliza más "castrar" que "capar"? ¿Es "capar" un verbo conocido en todas partes o solamente en algunas regiones de España?**

Comment: Ya por curiosidad, ¿qué entendía él como _tener capado al gato_? ¿Tal vez tenerle cortado el acceso al exterior?

Comment: *Capar* en el País Vasco se entiende perfectamente, yo diría que se usa mas que castrar.

Comment: Yo diría que la respuesta a esta pregunta puede estar complicada. El hecho de que dos personas de la misma ciudad hayan tenido ese problema demuestra que la preferencia de uso no va por región, sino por estudios. Si has estudiado algo que te ha enseñado que "capar" significa "restringir el acceso", tenderás a usar "castrar". Si no, pues "capar" se entenderá como "castrar".

Comment: Aca en Argentina, puntualmente Buenos Aires es mas comun el termino castrar, inclusive en campañas de ONGs o goburnamentales hablan de programas de castracion. Aunque cada tanto encontras gente que dice capar, mas que nada en gente mayor.

Comment: En Valencia se entienden ambos, pero es más frecuente el uso de castrar. Capar lo suelo usar más en el contexto internet/redes (Ej.: capar el acceso a una red a través de un puerto, etc.)

Comment: En Galicia se entienden ambos. Personalmente _capar_ me suena más vulgar y más general (quizás por su uso en informática), mientras que _castrar_ me suena más técnico y concreto.

Comment: Esta es de esas preguntas que tiene que tener una respuesta community wiki. En Colombia se usan indistintamente ambas palabras. La adiciono

Comment: @walen lo acabo de agregar como respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Argentina**: Más común castrar pero se entiende capar (usado principalmente por gente mayor)

**Colombia**: Se usan indistintamente ambas palabras.

**Galicia**: Se entienden los dos

**País Vasco**: Se entiende perfectamente, yo diría que se usa más que castrar

**Valencia**: Se entienden ambos, pero es más frecuente el uso de castrar

Comment: Será en el resto de Colombia que se conoce el término "capar" pero aquí en Cúcuta nadie tiene ni la menor idea de lo que significa, es más, mucha gente no conoce el significado de castrar, pero en teoria es más usado "castrar" que capar, almenos aquí en Cúcuta - Colombia.

Answer (score 4):

En el País Vasco *capar* se entiende perfectamente como sinónimo de *castrar*. Yo diría que en el habla coloquial se usa más *capar* aunque es solo mi impresión.

También se usa *capar* en el entorno informático para decir que algo está límitado o restringido, p.e.: *«Tengo capado el acceso a internet en mi equipo»*.

En el ejemplo que pones, hablando de un animal, no creo que nadie tuviera dudas sobre el significado y no se me ocurre que otra cosa podría significar tener un gato capado.

Comment: Pienso que la etimología es diferente: capar en informática parece robado al inglés. Se encuentra en otros idiomas no parecidas (Finés) en el sentido informático (O al menos en el jargon) quando la palabra capón (chapon) se encuentra en francés para describir un gallo castrado.

Answer (score 2):

Acá en Argentina, puntualmente Buenos Aires, es más común el término castrar, inclusive en campañas de ONGs o gubernamentales que hablan de programas de castración. Aunque cada tanto encontrás gente que dice `capar`, más que nada gente mayor.

Answer (score 1):

En Canarias se entienden las dos. Yo diría que capar se suele usar más para animales de granja (como cerdos) y castrar para mascotas (perros y gatos).

Comment: Y castrar también a las personas http://dle.rae.es/?id=7s5Q5vV **castrato** 1. m. Mús. Cantante al que se castraba en la infancia para que conservara el timbre de voz agudo.

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia capar tiene otro par de acepciones:
Un uso un poco más alegórico: por ejemplo, cuando una novia no deja salir al novio a fiestas o lo que sea, se puede decir "uy, la novia lo tiene capado" (no creo haber escuchado el caso inverso).
También capar, por lo menos en Bogotá, tiene el uso de dar un golpe fuerte en la zona genital de un hombre: "A Juan lo caparon de un balonazo".

Answer (score 1):

De pequeño me explicaron que capar es para los animales, castrar para los humanos. Pero viendo la definición ahora no lo tengo claro. Lo que es seguro es que capar se usa para más cosas en el sentido de restringir(como decían en algún otro comentario), y castrar siempre es para el tema genital.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser significativamente distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a la respuesta aceptada. Dale al [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación.  En qué país o región te criaste, si no te molesta decir?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí en Venezuela es mas común utilizar el término **castrar**. Capar ciertamente lo utilizan los más ancianos, sin embargo se conoce.

Answer (score 0):

yo había escuchado la diferencia de capar y castrar siempre como que la diferencia fundamental es el órgano sexual a extirpar.

Tuve esta discusión con mi mujer a cuenta del gato porque le vamos a capar, esto es vamos a extraerle los testículos, los huevámenes esos que tiene. Yo soy del país Vasco ella también y entendemos que capar es eso.

Yo entiendo por castrar cortar lo que es el pene, pero cortar el pene-pene, no hacer fimosis, cortar el tronco ese que tiene ahí. Yo escuché claro que la castración en ese término es una cosa que se hace con animales enfermos, que yo conozco un gato que está castrado porque tenía una infección en el pene y había que cortar.

En Internet también dicen que castrar es estilizar, y puede ser algo químico sin cortar nada.

Mi pareja duda de que castrar sea lo que yo digo, ella dice que simplemente se le llama mutilar a eso, pero claro mutilar es todo, también es mutilar hacerse un piercing si nos ponemos técnicos.

A ver si hay alguien más aquí que valide o invalide una definición u otra, y si realmente castrar no se usa para cortar penes. Pero la diferencia de capar para los testículos y castrar para los penes la he oído mucho.

Realmente no es algo que me preocupe, mi mujer no me va a castrar o lo contrario por esta discusión, pero sí que me gustaría saber si tengo la razón, me gusta mucho decir a mi mujer que tengo razón y que ella está equivocada, es una forma de poder paliar los sufrimientos inherentes de este matrimonio.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!